# Loading a table view (inside a view controller) with SQLite information

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, sqlite

I have a view that is inserting information into the database. This view displays that information inside a table view (top half of view is being used for something else)

I have the view controller's class, an object class, and a table view cell class (this is what's throwing me off I think because the image and text labels are in here whereas the actual database information is in the view controller).

Here's the NSObject class:

```
// car.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject {
    NSString *displayedMake;
    NSString *displayedModel;
    NSString *displayedImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *displayedMake;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *displayedModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *displayedImage;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u;

@end 

//car.m
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car
@synthesize displayedMake, displayedModel, displayedImage;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u {
    self.displayedMake = n;
    self.displayedModel = d;
    self.displayedImage = u;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Here's the table view cell class:

```
//DisplayCarsCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DisplayCarsCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *carImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *makeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *modelLabel;
@end

//DisplayCarsCell.m
#import "DisplayCarsCell.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation DisplayCarsCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code           
    }
    return self;
}    
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{       
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}    
@end
```

And finally, the view controller:

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
    //NSString    *databasePath;
    sqlite3     *carsDB;
    NSArray     *carImages;
   NSMutableArray *cars;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *cars;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;    
@end


//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DisplayCarsCell.h"
#import "Car.h"

@interface ViewController () 
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize cars;

-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cars.db"];
}    
-(void) openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String],&carsDB) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(carsDB);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}        
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Opens the database and creates the table if its the first time       
    [self readCarsFromDatabase];            
}        
- (void)readCarsFromDatabase
{
    // Setup the database object
    //sqlite3 *database;        
    // Init the animals Array
    cars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];       
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    [self openDB];
    const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apps (name text, id text, image text)";            
        if (sqlite3_exec(carsDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"create db");
        }
        //Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access          
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from apps";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;           
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(carsDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {                
         // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
         while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
         // Read the data from the result row               
         //image, or first column in table
         NSString *displayedImage=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];                        
         //name, or second column in table
         NSString *displayedMake=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];                    
         //model, or third column in table
         NSString *displayedModel=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];                    
         NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@",displayedImage, displayedMake, displayedModel);
                _status.text = displayedMake;                
         NSLog(@"here");
         // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
         Car *carObject = [Car alloc];
         carObject.displayedImage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];                   
         // Add the animal object to the animals Array
         [cars addObject:carObject];
         //NSLog(@"%@",displayedImage);
            }                               
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(carsDB) );
        }            
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);                    
            sqlite3_close(carsDB);    
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}    
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return carImages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DisplayCarsCell";        
    DisplayCarsCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[DisplayCarsCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }        
    // Configure the cell...        
    //UIImage *displayedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:
    //[carImage objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];        
    //   Car *carObj = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
    ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Car *car = (Car *)[viewController.cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    //[cell setImage:car.displayedImage];        
    return cell;        
}        
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // TODO: Select Item
    NSLog(@"Selected");}    
@end
```

The view controller itself is getting the array of data obviously from readCarsFromDatabase and is logging each row of the database correctly on viewDidLoad (did this to make sure that part wasn't wrong), but I need it to update the rows of the table view that is inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `reloadData` for your tableview once you're done adding records to `cars`, for example at the end of `readCarsFromDatabase`. I don't see an `IBOutlet` for the `UITableView`, but if it was simply `tableView`, then you'd add a line after `sqlite3_close` that says:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Obviously, make sure the table view's delegate is set to be your view controller.

---

Also, I would have thought that the following lines from your view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that currently say:

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Car *car = (Car *)[viewController.cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

should be changed to simply say:

```
Car *car = self.cars[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I changed those things, but I'm still missing something. The prototype cells have an image and two labels (in the table view cell class), that aren't being acknowledged in the view controller by displayedImage, displayedMake, or displayedModel.

Comment: @user2471957 Did you specify the `DisplayCarsCell` as the class for your cell in your cell prototype? Does the prototype in your table view also specify your cell identifier, `DisplayCarsCell`? You `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should never return `nil` from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` if you use a cell prototype. When using cell prototypes, your code should _not_ be manually creating `DisplayCarsCell` and if it does, it won't work because your `IBOutlet` references won't be hooked up.

Comment: DisplayCarsCell is the class for the cells, also it is set as the cell identifier. I remove the cell == nil, but still nothing.

Comment: Hit send on accident, Car *car = self.cars[indexPath.row]; is also not being used @Rob

Comment: @user2471957 You say "Car *car = self.cars[indexPath.row]; is also not being used." What you you mean by "not being used?" That it's not getting to that line? That's indicative of either (a) failure to specify the delegate; or (b) `numberOfRowsInSection` not returning a  value greater than zero. Put a log in `numberOfRowsInSection` and see what you're getting for count. Identify whether the problem is basic table view linkage, or the data itself.

Comment: I mean it's definitely a data issue.. I changed `return carImages.count` to `return cars.count` in numberOfRowsInSection, that was a stupid mistake because I had been using carImages earlier before I changed it to just cars. So now this returns basically the prototype cells (literally Label, Label, Label, Label, Label) but without any of the actual information from the database (Images, the actual labels) And what I meant by not being used, is that an unused variable.

Comment: Let me clarify data issue, I'm not 100% on adding objects, and I am logging everything retrieved from the database and it shows up fine in the log but never shows in the actual view. So this line in my code NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@",displayedImage, displayedMake, displayedModel); returns great. There's a huge change it's the end of this where I add the object that I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @user2471957 I'm having a hard time following where the code now stands and what the open issue is. Perhaps you can either update the question with the current code and what the current issue is. Or upload the project to github or just compress the project and upload it somewhere we can take a look.